# Generally valid way to execute a javascript only once (via cookies)?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, static, popup

I'd like to add an onbeforeunload javascript, asking the user to bookmark the page (there's a small button in the header for that purpose).

The problem is, no matter if they'd like to bookmark it, it's pointless and annoying after running once.

So, what's a generic solution to stop a javascript from running more than once?

Thanks,

Emilia.

**EDIT:**

Yes, I guess an onload event would be more appropriate?

I don't really want to add "big red buttons"...

Any basic example how a IP validation + script would look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say it's already a bad idea to use a pop up when the user wants to exit the page even if it is only once, it's annoying and obtrusive. I suggest you place a big button on site itself if you want to call the visitor to an action, bookmarking in this case.

If you still want to though, you should use IP validation and not cookies, cookies are temporal, they can be removed by the user, and visitors will not like to be presented the same suggestion over and over.

Comment: I agree with this, you could animate the button, or slide something into the side of the page (once) to grab attention if you wanted.

Comment: Right, onunload seems kind of inappropriate, but wouldn't user consider the big, flashy "call-to-action" thing more annoying?